# Confusing editor tabs (page tab vs design tab) and zone (widget zone vs webpart zone)

Tags: kentico

Can anyone help to explain

1. What are the relation between them?
2. How they affect each others?

Answer (score 1):

On design tab:

- you need design permission
- you can edit the template
- you can manage widgets and web parts
- you can manage zones and specify zone type (editor, user, group, none=webparts)
- you can edit the template

Page tab:

- you do not need design permission
- you can`t edit the template
- you can manage widgets only
- you can`t manage zones

In general, design is for more skilled users (developers, admin etc) who can edit code (templates, transformations etc). In fact, on design tab, you can execute your own code and access database directly pretty easy.
In comparison - page tab is for marketers and non-technical people. Page tab is more restrictive and it`s harder to mess something up.

Relations: On design tab, you are editing the template. The template is shared across multiple pages, this means you are editing the other pages as well. Once you edit the page on the page tab, this page 'lives' own lifecycle - this means, the page is not affected by changes on design tab anymore (you can still reset zones to default with widget actions web part).

In general, widgets require less skilled users (in comparison to web parts).

Comment: "you can still reset zones to default with widget actions web part" < How do you do that? Set Widget zone type to None?

Comment: If you set widget zone type to none => you can only add web parts to these zones (only on design tab). You can learn more about 'Widget actions' web part [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/developing-websites/preparing-widgets-for-users/setting-up-widget-zones-on-pages#Settingupwidgetzonesonpages-Addingwidgetactionstopages).
After restarting (reset widgets button) your page tab is synced with design tab.

Comment: 'Widget actions' web part has a field which is to target a specific widget zone with the widget zone ID.
Is that mean I will need to add 'Widget actions' web part for each widget zone?

Comment: Short answer: no. Tooltip says: _Indicates if the 'Reset to default' button should be displayed. It allows users to reset all widget zones of the specified type on the page to their default content._

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Martin shared, Widgets are based off of a webpart and it's code. 
 Widgets are essentially preconfigured webparts for content editors.  Widgets are very specific to a page and cannot be set for multiple pages like a webpart can.

Webparts can be setup on 1 template and that 1 template can be used across many pages displaying different content on each page dynamically.

Widget zones have to be configured at the template level in the webpart zone.  Once a webpart zone is configured to use Widgets, it cannot have webparts in it.  You will have to add another webpart zone above or below to allow webparts to be added.

If you have multiple editors on your site who want the flexibility to setup their own pages and design, you're better off to use widget zones and allow the editors to do this.  This allows for a more flexible environment for the editor.  On the flip side if you want to ensure your site and the different areas are consistent you might not want to enable the widget zones because the content editors can then add whatever they want to those areas.  This is where a template and a webpart would be more structured and consistent.